# UIPreviewInteraction on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, 3dtouch

I'm wanting to add a UIPreviewInteraction to my `UITableViewCell` so I can recreate something similar to Apple Music's 3D Touch action. Here's what I've done in my `UITableView's` `cellForRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        let interactionView = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UIView

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            var planPreviewInteraction = UIPreviewInteraction(view: interactionView)
            previewInteraction.delegate = self
        }

        return cell!

    }
```

and then I call the delegate functions

```
func previewInteraction(_ previewInteraction: UIPreviewInteraction, didUpdatePreviewTransition transitionProgress: CGFloat, ended: Bool) {
    let buttonPosition = previewInteraction.view?.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition!)

    animator.fractionComplete = transitionProgress

}

func previewInteractionDidCancel(_ previewInteraction: UIPreviewInteraction) {

}
```

But the delegate methods are never called. It doesn't seem like the `UITableViewCell` is detecting the `UIPreviewInteraction`. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

`interactionView` is deallocating at the end of `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method.

Make `interactionView` as a property